# XCode 6, using custom fonts in iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

If i use custom fonts (without providing "UIAppFonts" key in plist) in Xcode 6, but my project still support iOS7, will the custom fonts work also on iOS7 (without the plist key)?

the Apple docs states only
*"Custom iOS fonts. Interface Builder renders embedded custom fonts during design time, giving a more accurate preview of how the finished app will look, with correct dimensions."*

Comment: Why don't you test this yourself in a simulator or device?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two unrelated issues. the `UIAppFonts` key is required for your app to include custom fonts, and is [supported back to iOS 3.2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html). The new feature in Xcode 6 is that these fonts are available in Interface Builder so you can specify the fonts in IB, and preview your UI as it will look with your custom fonts.